# large-file-upload-enhancements Microsoft Graph java sdk 6.1.0

Tags: microsoft-graph-sdks

I am trying to generate an upload session as described in the document "https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-java/blob/dev/docs/upgrade-to-v6.md#large-file-upload-enhancements".
is described.
Unfortunately, the error message "Item not found" appears. The file does not exist either. What is the correct call to create a new file?

The variable destination is set to "/testfolder/test.txt"
My Code:

```
            DriveItemUploadableProperties driveItemUploadableProperties = new DriveItemUploadableProperties();
            driveItemUploadableProperties.setName(FilenameUtils.getName(destination));
            driveItemUploadableProperties.setFileSize(streamSize);
            Map<String, Object> additionalData = new HashMap<>();
            additionalData.put("@microsoft.graph.conflictBehavior", "replace");
            driveItemUploadableProperties.setAdditionalData(additionalData);

            CreateUploadSessionPostRequestBody uploadSessionPostRequestBody = new CreateUploadSessionPostRequestBody();
            uploadSessionPostRequestBody.setItem(driveItemUploadableProperties);
            UploadSession uploadSession=null;
            try
            {
            uploadSession = graphClient.drives().byDriveId(drive.getId()).items().byDriveItemId("root/"+destination).createUploadSession()
                    .post(uploadSessionPostRequestBody);
            }catch (ApiException gse) {
                if (gse.getResponseStatusCode() == 404) {
                
                }
            }
```

Comment: With

uploadSession = graphClient.drives().byDriveId(drive.getId()).items().byDriveItemId("root:/"+destination+":").createUploadSession()
                    .post(uploadSessionPostRequestBody);

it work's well, but now I got an 400 Error Code by upload an file. I have tried all combination of DriveItemUploadableProperties  and SliceSize with no success. :-(